# Getting Visual Studio to see my namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

Hi I'm coming from Java so I'm new to C++ and Visual Studio.  I have a namespace file that I want to use in my main project but I can't figure out how to get the project to see the namespace.  I've tried just putting the namespace file in the same folder as the main code and also dragging the file into Resource Files in my project.  I can't find any instructions on how to do this, help?

EDIT: My namespace is in a .cpp file.

Comment: I am not sure what a namespace file is, could you be more specific: .h, .cpp, .lib, .dll, etc?

Comment: .cpp  What file type should a namespace be?

Comment: Please add an example of what you mean with a *namespace file*. In C++, namespaces are not bound to files (you can have multiple namespaces in one file, and declare names in the same namespace in different files).

Comment: I just mean a .cpp file in which I have defined my own namespace (which contains classes and functions) and nothing else.  I know they're not bound to files, it just would be nice to have it contained in a file for modularity.  My problem is getting a project access to the namespace, ie, calling MyNamespace::myFunction().

Comment: @SUCHANOOB You typically declare the namespace and interface (i.e class declaration, function declaration) then define the functions, and classes you declared in the header in your .cpp files. When you include the header you should have access to the namespace, and it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you typically create header files (.h files) that provide declarations of classes and functions.  Corresponding definitions are specified through source files (.CPP files).  The header file is included when you want to use what was declared in it.  Source files are never included.  This is the basic design pattern.  Any basic set of c++ tutorials will teach you this.